ESTA applications
I applied in the past for two kinds of visa on the same day.
C1/D + B.
I was denied on the B visa and got the C1 and went to the US many times.
Now I’m asking for an ESTA and there is a denied visa question. I didn’t know what to reply cause that was 10 years ago. I replied “no”
Will I get a rejection?

Does the question put a time limit on how long ago any denial occurred? If not, you have no option but to answer honestly. You might get a rejection, however lying will almost certainly get you a rejection and an entry ban if discovered.

It is risky. Try to cancel your application and apply again with correct answer, or just go with the VISA track.
